# How to set up input stream in PHP/ PHPstorm when debugging?

Tags: php, io, phpstorm, xdebug

I've almost never worked with input streams in PHP, but I'm forced to because of the site hackerrank.com, which writes their problems for more "streamy" languages like C++ or Java. I've figured out how to handle it, but I would like to use the debugger in an IDE and "write" to the input stream so I can test my program.

A simple script for example would be:

```
<?php
$stdin = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$wordCount = trim(fgets($stdin));

for ($i = 0; $i < $wordCount; $i++) {
$array1 = str_split(trim(fgets($stdin)));
...
```

How do I write to whatever "php://stdin" is?

Answer (score 1):

A little late, and not the most politically correct answer, but if you're just testing, you have two choices:

When you run in script mode inside PHPStorm it fires up a console inside the IDE, there you can copy and paste any input and the debugger will work just fine.

And the second choice, if you don't want to copy and paste, you can create a stdin.txt and change the line of code to

```
$handle = fopen ("stdin.txt","r");
```

Inside the stdin.txt you can have the testing input. Be sure to change it back whenever you're finished testing.